# How to find the means of all columns of a matrix simultaneously

Tags: r

I have a matrix and I want to find the means of all the columns at the same time. Can anyone help do this? Below is my data.

```
dta=matrix(c(11,12,10,9,15,8),nrow=2,ncol=3)
```

How do I find the means of all columns simultaneously.

Comment: Next time try search in doc by yourself using `??mean`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `colMeans` is right for that:

```
> colMeans(dta)
[1] 11.5  9.5 11.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `colMeans`:

```
> dta=matrix(c(11,12,10,9,15,8),nrow=2,ncol=3)
> dta
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   11   10   15
[2,]   12    9    8
> colMeans(dta)
[1] 11.5  9.5 11.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to remember that you can also use `apply` over the columns:

```
dta = matrix(c(11, 12, 10, 9, 15, 8), nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
cmeans = apply(dta, 2, mean)
print(cmeans)

[1] 11.5  9.5 11.5
```